# Does shuffledRowRDD from different ShuffleMapStages are created in parallel for SortMergeJoin

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am just trying to understand the internals of different shuffle strategies. This one is my try on SMJ (SortMergeJoin) and I am stuck on a part with some confusion.

I have read two JSON files from HDFS (2 DFs created with 2 partitions each) and performed a inner join for which I made the Catalyst pipeline to select SMJ . I have default 200 value for shuffle partitions.

It executed in 4 stages as below and also executed the 6 java functions generated by CodeGen on different stages as you can see below.

[image]

I will directly come to my questions here

1. As I understood Stage 2 and Stage 3 read the data from source, executed any pipelined transformations using CodeGen code , generated and written shuffle data  files 1 each for each input partition (so 2 files) in which each file containing blocks corresponding to each shuffle partition (so 200 blocks) and blocks are sorted by shuffle partition id. And it also writes 1 index files for each data file with block positions in file. Does my understanding is correct ? If so Does the data within each block is sorted by join key at this stage itself? Because I can see the  CodeGen code with sorting is only executed in next stage (Stage 4)  !

[image]

2. I can see 200 tasks are doing shuffle reads for each blocks and creating one shuffledRowRDDs each for each mapPartitionRDD from stage2 and stage3 in stage4. But there are 200 blocks to be read  for each mapPartitionRDDs of stage2 and stage3 right. So does a single reducer task in stage 4 say , with task ID 0 will read block 0 corresponding to partition 0 from shuffle files of each mapPartitionRDDs of stage2 and stage3 in parallel ? If so how it will know that which block is read from which stage , using the shuffle ID (that uniquely identifies the stage) ?

[image]

3. When I executed shuffleHashJoin instead of SMJ, I can see similar stages . But the difference is stage4 is executed with hash join instead of sortMergeJoin. So Does this mean that shuffle phase is same for both ? I read ShuffleHashJoin generates one shuffle file each for each shuffle partition from each input partition . So does that mean , here if it is SHJ , 2*200=400 shuffle files will be created from  each mapOutPutRDD in stage2 and stage3? Does SHJ also creates index files along with data files ?

[image]

Comment: why is scrapy tagged?

Comment: @Alexander : Sorry that was a typo. Removed it